# Where is the dividing line between what database interactions are on-topic vs off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I usually feel a question about databases is off-topic on Stack Overflow if it's about:

- Database server installation, maintenance (including backup/restore), troubleshooting
- Usage of tools and/or utilities (SQL Plus, Toad, Studio, etc.)
- Code issues due to Data Source, Connection parameters or setup
- BULK operations
- Effectiveness of complex data schema and index expressions

It boils down to cases when an average enterprise app developer would seek a Database Administrator's (DBA's) assistance and/or guidance.

I understand that a person asking such questions could be primarily a programmer, but acting as a jack of all trades when all of the above falls in their lap, particularly when they simply are not afforded the luxury of having specialized DBAs available in their organization/company, but on Stack Overflow we need to have a dividing line between what's on-topic and off-topic for questions asked here.

Does the above make sense to you as a starting point for where to set the on-topic/off-topic line for database related questions here on Stack Overflow? What other things might be off-topic?

Comment: I'm somewhat on the fence about "BULK operations" and "Effectiveness of complex data schema and index expressions". How to streamline operations, or structure data and accesses would be veritable considerations for "normal" programming tasks as well.

Comment: @MisterM - I actually meant stand-alone bulk loads. Like "I have gazillion rows to append to my table and it takes forever" kind of complaints.

Comment: It is probably best if you post some example here, because only the first bullet in that list is guaranteed off-topic. Let's not steamroll ahead and keep the option on the table that your "feeling" is simply incorrect.

Answer (score -9):

Do you need to understand what you are doing other than chaging arbitrary parameters to accomplish what you want? If you do not, then you are not programming. Anyone (that has the neccesary privileges) can load bulk data on a database by simply copy-n-pasting the command or using the gui. Same with installation, most of it is trivial "next, next, next, finish/reboot". All of those are pure administrative tasks. On programming, you do not need administrative privileges to accomplish your goal (ie. write a program that accepts inputs and produces an output).

The last one usually devolves in a drag race or "test it yourself". Yes, there are specific algorithms that are more efficient, but there's a point of dismishing returns, and rarely I've found questions here with answers addressing those on DB operations. Programmers tend to worry more about what "works for me", DBA's worry more about "what works for all users". If you worry about the later, programmers rarely offer satisfactory solutions.

Comment: That first sentence is an overgeneralization that someone can probably find an exception to... I'd suggest removing it, as it doesn't add much to the answer...

Comment: @Cerbrus it's a question that you need to ask yourself if you want to understand the fundamental concepts behind the site topic. Without the first sentence you do not have the first paragraph, and without it you do not have the later one. It's a generalization, becuause no one will ever find anything that will be universally recognized as programming that doesn't fulfill that condition. That's why despite being a generalization, it's something that will be impossible to find an exception to. Because programming is esentially about creating a process, not about their inputs/outputs.